# Will Google Play users included in testing email lists always receive in-app items for free?

Tags: android-studio, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have added the accounts of some Google Play users to email lists for testing purposes, as shown in Image 1.

When I apply the email list for internal testing of an app, these test users can purchase in-app items of the app without actual deductions, as illustrated in Image 2.

However, I've noticed that Google Play users included in the testing email list can purchase all in-app items across all my apps without actual deductions. Isn't this an unusual scenario? Something seems off.

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77541667/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 1):

For paid apps, if you are using an internal test track, than anybody on the testing email list can install it for free. If you are using an open or closed testing track instead, even those on the testing email list will have to pay for the app. Though I have not done in-app-purchases myself, I would assume that it functions the same way. I would recommend trying to use a closed or open testing track and see if your testers will have to pay for in-app-purchases then.

From the Google Play Console docs:
[image: Google Android Developer Docs]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is one of three scenarios:

1. your verifying this assumption using an admin account or owner account
2. you've added these tester to other apps without remembering
3. your testing using a phone with multiple Google Play accounts, one of them are owner or already internal tester. Google play will not use the current account always.

This should not happen, use a fresh email on a fresh phone that you've never used before add it to a new list and add this list to one app only then test on other apps, you will find out that you can not get any paid item for free.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play users who are `whitelisted` as `license-test` in the Play Console can make purchases without being charged. This is for general testing and when the app goes to QA.